# Git undoes changes from remote branch unintentionally

Tags: git, version-control

We've got what I think is a typical git setup, with an "origin" repository that multiple users, each with their own repositories, fetch and push to, and each user manages their own branches, and then merges to the master branch.

However, a commit and a push from a user has resulted in changes from another user being undone: both users had modified the same files, and I wanted, and expected, that these changes would be merged together, and I'm fairly sure this commit didn't show anything to do with conflicts.

I'm not sure how to investigate what happened, let alone how to prevent this from happening again. How can I find out what happened, and what could be done to prevent it in the future?

Edit: from @antak 's answer requesting clarification, the changes are "undone" not from a delete of the commit from the history, but what looks like, from a git show, that they manually removed they changes (but they didn't do this deliberately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `A`'s pushed and undid user `B`'s work in file `C`...

How do you define *"undone"*?  Did `B`'s commit disappear from history?

If the answer is no, here's possibly what happened:

1. User `A` pulled.
2. User `A` *overwrote* file `C` in the working-tree with an older version he/she had modified elsewhere.
3. User `A` committed and pushed.

You could easily determine if this is the case by reviewing the history of `C` with an option like `git log -p`.

If the answer is yes, the only way this could happen (short of a glitch in `git`) is if `A` had pushed with `git push -f`.  If this is the case, you can prevent it from happening in future by denying non-fast-forwards pushes to `origin`.  This can be done by setting the `git config` variable `receive.denyNonFastForwards` to `true` on the repository that houses `origin`.

Comment: We eventually discovered that this was what was happening, as the user was (needlessly) working remotely from their own git repo and uploading to it via SCP. I'll post the details in another answer, but accept this one.

Answer (score 1):

Ask them if they used push -f? If you use the -f flag, it will overwrite the branch with your changes, without regard to other changes. It might have happened that one developer tried pushing, git rejected the push because other changes have already happened since he started working, and did not know that he should have used fetch/pull/merge, and just did a push -f.

If it turns out that this is the case, you can consider setting receive.denyNonFastForwards to true on the git server, this will disallow rewriting history (and in turn, using push -f to clobber other changes)

Comment: I can't be completely sure, but I suspect no.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered what was happening. One user was editing files remotely from their own git repository, and uploading changed files via SCP. They were also fetching/merging into this repository, but then *not* always downloading the changed files to their local work area. So the chain of events:

- Download to their local work-area from their git repo
- Make some changes on their local work-area
- Fetch + merge in their git repo all changes from other users
- Upload from their local work-area to their git repo (thus losing changes from the previous step)
- Commit